# how to show activity when a specifed file size changes at any point of time?

Tags: android

I want to show an activity based on following condition.

suppose consider a file is in a particular location inside a sdcard.When ever the file size changes i want to show an activity at any point of time.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement this as like so.

- Implement a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that checks the file in a regular basis
- Then put a [notification to the status bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) if changed
- If clicked on status bar event the [launch your Activity](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/)

Comment: There's a class `android.os.FileObserver` which can be used to monitor file changes instead of regular checking.